# How to add different styles for different features in openlayers3

Tags: openlayers-3

I want to add style for a particular ol.Feature in OpenLayers3,I tried the way explained below but its not working.

```
vectorsrc.addFeature(
                        new ol.Feature({
                            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(0,0).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
style: new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
                anchor: [0.5, 46],
                size: [32, 48],
                anchorXUnits: 'pixels',
                anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                src: '/image/icon.png'
            }))
                        })
                    );
```

Answer (score 1):

The style can not be set in the constructor of a feature (Yes, it is a bit confusing. If you are interested, [here](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/2274) is a discussion about that issue). You'll have to call `feature.setStyle(..)`.